# Doctrine Mapping : discriminators?

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I have 3 classes : `A, B, and C`.
B extends A and C extends B.
Let's put name on these so we understand better.

Person `C` extends HumanBeing `B` extends Mammal `A`

But I also have some classes, like `Cow`, which extends directly Mammal without extending Person (seems legit... i guess).

The only reason why Person is extending `HumanBeing` is because at some point, in some other entity, I need an attribute linked to a `HumanBeing` (inherited by `Person`, but also by other classes like `FanOfJustinBieber` or `PrometheusMovieScriptWriter`).

Actually, the `HumanBeing` entity is just a linking table, and in my dream world it should be :

- id
- linked_id (which can be a `Person`, a `FanOfJustinBieber`, or `PrometheusMovieScriptWriter`)
- discriminator

With no inheritance whatsoever, and `Person` extending directly `Mammal`, juste like `Cow`.

But I can't find a way to tell Doctrine that my class `HumanBeing` needs a discriminator and needs to have an attribute that points towards either `Person`, `FanOfJustinBieber` and `PrometheusMovieScriptWriter`, moreover if they do not share a common extended class anymore (except from `Mammal`, but since there are a lot of class extending `Mammal`, i guess I can't use this one).

Here is the scheme I imagine :

`Person,Cow,FanOfJustinBieber   ->    Mammal`

`HumanBeing: {id, linked_id (Person, ...), discriminator}`

`SomeOtherEntity: {id, someAttribute, HumanBeing}`

I have trouble finding out the declaration of the class HumanBeing, and especially the Doctrine annotations.

For `Person`, this seems straightforward (with a `@MappedSuperClass()` on top of `Mammal`) ; and even easier for `SomeOtherEntity` (`@ManyToOne`).

Any help would be greatly appreciated !

Thanks :)

Comment: Let me be sure that I've understood: you don't know how to indicate the discriminator field?

Comment: Have you thought of using [Class Table Inheritance](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#class-table-inheritance)